# How I can read a shapefile with R. I have few errors with readOGR

Tags: r, error

I  have  a  problem   with   reading  my  shapefile. The  error:

> Cannot open data source

In addition:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> path[1]="D:/Pentru  Disertatie/De pe RRRRRRR/ro_judete_poligon": The
> system cannot find the file specified
>
> 2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> path[1]="D:\Pentru  Disertatie\De pe RRRRRRR\ro_judete_poligon": The
> system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please edit your post and include the actual code that produced the error - not just the error message! Also helpful if you provide more information about what you're doing and if the shapefile opens successfully in other apps such as QGIS.

Comment: Try with `raster::shapefile("D:/Pentru Disertatie/De pe RRRRRRR/ro_judete_poligon.shp")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code I think that the error may come from the space you leave here:

"D:/Pentru Disertatie/**De pe RRRRRRR**/ro_judete_poligon" and also not to specify the extension "**ro_judete_poligon.shp**".

With the package "sf" you can use the following code :

```
library("sf")

poly = read_sf(folder path/ro_judete_poligon.shp")
```